# Why would all of my files have duplicates with a '~' at the end?

Tags: php, git, codeigniter

I am building a site with code igniter and I am using git for version control. I am not sure why, but duplicates of my files keep popping up. If I have a home.php controller there is also a home.php~ controller. It is not really causing a problem with the functionality of the site, but it is weird and I don't like it. What exactly is going on?

My editor was set to backup files. I just had to turn it off. 
[image]

Comment: It sounds as if one problem is that you're editing your live site directly, instead of having the site content prepared off-line, then testing it, then putting it into production.

Comment: no I am editing it locally. I just have the whole lamp environment installed on my computer. directory is /var/www/codeigniter and url is localhost/codeigniter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tilde files are automatic backup files of the last version created by the text editors. You can turn off this automatic creation by editing the preferences of the text editor you use.

Answer (score 2):

Those are probably temporary / backup files created by an editor like emacs, vim etc. Anyway, such files would have nothing to do with git.

Comment: Or Emacs, AFAIK. In fact, I think vim got the convention from Emacs.

Comment: I have been using gedit. I am thinking it might be because I am developing on a fresh installation of ubuntu and am working as root. my codeigniter project is at /var/www/CodeIgniter. Could that cause these files?

Comment: @SpencerCooley - Yeah gedit does it too. See here: http://www.ubuntu4life.com/Close-gedit-backup-function

Answer (score 2):

Conventially, the ~ suffix indicates a backup copy. It is usually created by an editor which saves a backup copy of the file (with the old contents) when you make changes to it. You area probably using an editor that does this.

I believe the convention to use ~ as a suffix for backup files started with a long time ago with emacs.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs uses that convention to name the backup files it creates; have you been using Emacs? It's an old convention, so it's possible there are other things that use that format too.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've been editting with vim and don't have the `backup` option disabled.  By default vim will backup file edits with a file of the same name suffixed with `~`.  Try adding the following to your .vimrc

```
set nobackup
```

Answer (score 1):

As ~ files are backup files, I have found backups useful when there has been an issue saving or the editor closes unexpectedly.

I prefer to have the backup files, but add these files to the .gitignore file to prevent them being added to source control:

Add this line to the .gitignore file to ignore files ending with a tilde ~:

```
*~
```